# Is any article needed before the word "interpreter" in the following sentence?

Tags: articles, bare-role-noun-phrases

I have asked this question on Grammarly.com too, but didn't get any answers.  English is not my first language and I'm trying to get better at it therefore I can't give much input or put my "research" here. Here is the sentence:

> Max had an opportunity to play the role of interpreter in an international film festival organised here.

Please explain if any article is needed or not.

Comment: Both with and without an article is fine, for this specific sentence. If you did want to use an article though, it'd be best to use *the* if there were no other interpreters other than Max, and *an* if there were multiple.

Comment: What Charles said.  It depends on what  exactly you want to say, since both "interpreter" and "the interpreter" can work.  Otherwise there are several other mistakes in the sentence:  "an opportunity" should be "the opportunity", "in an international film festival" should be "at an international film festival", and "organized here" should probably be "held here".

Comment: Andrew, I disagree with all of your corrections. "an opportunity" has difference nuance to "the opportunity", referring more to the nature of a job offer than a special treat type of opportunity. "In an international film festival" conveys nuance of a role within the film festival's organizational body, rather than simply on premises. "Organized here" and "held here" neither have the same meaning nor is one a replacement for the other, and either one could be correct and potentially imply the other's meaning in addition to its own.

Comment: I think the sentence is best as is. To put "the interpreter" would make it less good, in my opinion. I also think @Rhythmatic is correct.

Comment: Unless the interpreter role is clearly defined previously -- or that film festivals have only one interpreter -- adding "the" here confines the meaning of the sentence in a "look-at-me" sort of way. Just doesn't seem natural to use the article in this context.